# Group Messenging with 5.1 LG4

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

Question 1: I recently purchased the LG4 with 5.1. I noticed that when group messaging using the LG 5.1 stock messaging app. I don't see the name of the person replying. I only see a color bubble. In order to see who is responding, I have to click on the bubble. How can I see the name of the person w/out having to click on the bubble.

Question 2: How can I receive replies in one conversation? I am receiving responses individually. It makes it hard to follow the conversation.

Comment: That it does! Feel free to edit your question to include that information - I'll delete my old comment since it's no longer relevant. There are tons of messaging apps for Android - thus why I asked you to be specific. I don't know if LG's stock app is different from ASOP - I'll look into it to see what I can find.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. In the meantime, I downloaded textra. It seems to be working fine but I'd rather use the default messaging app.

Comment: Is it LG G4? Please mention the product link. I'm getting Google results for LG G4 only.